# How create a column that increase according to the value of another column

Tags: postgresql, field, auto-increment, unique-constraint

I have a table where I want to put all the information about articles use, and I need to create a column with autoincrement, where the `ID` can have the same value if the field (`tipo`) have another value, unique for this particular `ID`. For example:

```
ID  /  TIPO
1   /   AJE -- Is Ok
1   /   AJS -- Is Ok (because this Tipo is AJS, different from AJE)
1   /   SI    -- Is Ok
2   /   AJE  -- Is Ok (New ID)
2   /   AJE  -- Is Wrong, because ID=2, TIPO=AJE already exist.
```

I've done the unique sentence:

```
ALTER TABLE public.art_movimientos 
ADD CONSTRAINT uk_mov UNIQUE (id,tipo) USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index;
```

But how I can create the autoincrement covering two columns?

My table Code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.art_movimientos
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_art_movimientos'::regclass),
  tipo character(3) NOT NULL, -- Tipos de Valores:...
  documento integer,
  fecha_doc date[] NOT NULL,
  fecha_mov date[] NOT NULL,
  calmacen integer NOT NULL,
  status character(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDIENTE'::bpchar, -- PENDIENTE...
  mes integer NOT NULL,
  "año" integer NOT NULL,
  donado integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: As in "don't"? Serials are useful if the PK's value does not depend on the table's contents, which it would in this case. You'll probably be better of with `INSERT INTO art_movimientos SELECT max(id) + 1, tipo, ... FROM art_movimientos WHERE tipo = '...'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this situation by using an *before insert* trigger, mimicking the behaviour statedby @dhke:

```
CREATE TABLE art_movimientos
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, -- You don't want a serial, nor a default
  tipo character(3) NOT NULL, -- Tipos de Valores:...
  documento integer,
  fecha_doc date[] NOT NULL,
  fecha_mov date[] NOT NULL,
  calmacen integer NOT NULL,
  status character(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDIENTE'::bpchar, -- PENDIENTE...
  mes integer NOT NULL,
  "año" integer NOT NULL,
  donado integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

  /* You have actually a 2-column Primary Key */
  PRIMARY KEY (tipo, id)
```

);

```
-- Create a trigger function to generate 'id'
CREATE FUNCTION art_movimientos_insert_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    /* Compute "id", as the following id for a certain "tipo" */
    new.id = coalesce( 
                  (SELECT max(id) + 1 
                     FROM art_movimientos a 
                    WHERE a.tipo = new.tipo), 1); 
    return new; 
END 
$$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE ;

-- This trigger will be called whenever a new row is inserted, and "id" is 
-- not specified (i.e.: it defaults to null), or is specified as null
CREATE TRIGGER art_movimientos_ins_trg
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON art_movimientos
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE art_movimientos_insert_trigger();
```

You can then insert the following rows (*without* specifying the `id` column):

```
INSERT INTO art_movimientos
   (tipo, documento, fecha_doc, fecha_mov, calmacen, mes, "año")
VALUES
   ('AJE', 1, array['20170128'::date], array['20170128'::date], 1, 1, 2017), 
   ('AJS', 2, array['20170128'::date], array['20170128'::date], 1, 1, 2017), 
   ('SI',  3, array['20170128'::date], array['20170128'::date], 1, 1, 2017), 
   ('AJE', 4, array['20170128'::date], array['20170128'::date], 1, 1, 2017), 
   ('AJE', 5, array['20170128'::date], array['20170128'::date], 1, 1, 2017) ;
```

... and see that you get what you intended:

```
SELECT 
    id, tipo 
FROM 
    art_movimientos 
ORDER BY 
    documento ;


| id | tipo |
|----|------|
|  1 |  AJE |
|  1 |  AJS |
|  1 |  SI  |
|  2 |  AJE |
|  3 |  AJE |
```

You can check everything a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/074cc/1/0)  (which is a bit picky about PL/pgSQL functions and semicolons).

---

**Side note**: There can be a few corner cases where this procedure might fail within a transaction because of *deadlocks* and/or *race conditions*, if other transactions are also inserting data into the same table at the same time. So, your overall code should be able to handle aborted transactions, and retry them or show an error to the user.

Comment: so you suggest use a bigserial field, and set one primary key only?

Comment: It's normally easier, and will give one *key* to one row. Just now, you could have a row AJE123 (which happens to be the *last*), you delete it, and insert a new one. It will get again AJE123. The same *id* for two different things => leads to problems.